# asp.net implicitly cannot convert to in to in. an explicit conversion exist

Tags: system, using

im getting the following error. please help.  the error is cannot implicitly convert to int to int. my database table is set to int and I had remove the Null.

Comment: Please share a screenshot or at least more directly quote the error message. You don't need to convert `int` to `int`, so obviously one of those things is not a standard `System.Int32` (the type of object used for the `int` keyword in C#).

Comment: Can you show your code ? the line of code where the error triggered. so that we can evaluate further.

Comment: thanks here's the code:  FarmDBEntities db = new FarmDBEntities();

            int amount = (from x in db.Carts
                          where x.ClientID == userId
                          && x.IsInCart
                          select x.Amount).Sum();

Comment: im new here. how do I send a screen shot or my code?

Comment: This one, I resolved it. the issue was with master page where the master pagefile never populated to the Index page. I had to start over again. delete the index page and create a new one. that solves the issue